# How can i solve KeyError: 'ir.actions.view' odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

am a noob to odoo and am trying to build a custom module. I removed the menuitems on some of the views but i still got the same error. I got the error below when i tried to add a submenu to `farm_menu`. How do i make the menu work like this? 
**Animals**
   *feeds
   *feeding records

Your help is highly appreciated.

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 88, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.ui.menu', <function IrUiMenu.load_menus at 0x7f3f849090d0>, 2, None, ('en_US',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 88, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.ui.menu', <function IrUiMenu._visible_menu_ids at 0x7f3f848fc730>, frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 79, 80, 81, 82, 84, 85}), None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 1049, in get
    value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 62

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1005, in __get__
    value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 1051, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('ir.ui.menu(62,).action', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mustaf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 304, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/mustaf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 292, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 434, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1320, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1293, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/home/mustaf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1488, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/auth_signup/models/ir_http.py", line 19, in _dispatch
    return super(Http, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_http.py", line 22, in _dispatch
    return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/http_routing/models/ir_http.py", line 403, in _dispatch
    result = super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 207, in _dispatch
    return cls._handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 177, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 776, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 203, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 835, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 457, in web_client
    context = request.env['ir.http'].webclient_rendering_context()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/web/models/ir_http.py", line 17, in webclient_rendering_context
    'menu_data': request.env['ir.ui.menu'].load_menus(request.debug),
  File "</home/mustaf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-31>", line 2, in load_menus

  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 93, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_menu.py", line 234, in load_menus
    menu_roots = self.get_user_roots()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_menu.py", line 204, in get_user_roots
    return self.search([('parent_id', '=', False)])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1562, in search
    res = self._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_menu.py", line 135, in _search
    menus = menus._filter_visible_menus()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_menu.py", line 125, in _filter_visible_menus
    visible_ids = self._visible_menu_ids(request.debug if request else False)
  File "</home/mustaf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-28>", line 2, in _visible_menu_ids

  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 93, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_menu.py", line 94, in _visible_menu_ids
    action_menus = menus.filtered(lambda m: m.action and m.action.exists())
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4901, in filtered
    return self.browse([rec.id for rec in self if func(rec)])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4901, in <listcomp>
    return self.browse([rec.id for rec in self if func(rec)])
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_menu.py", line 94, in <lambda>
    action_menus = menus.filtered(lambda m: m.action and m.action.exists())
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1009, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1112, in determine_value
    record._prefetch_field(self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2843, in _prefetch_field
    result = records.read([f.name for f in fs], load='_classic_write')
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2781, in read
    self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2934, in _read_from_database
    values = [convert(value, target, validate=False) for value in values]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2934, in <listcomp>
    values = [convert(value, target, validate=False) for value in values]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 2032, in convert_to_cache
    if record.env[res_model].browse(int(res_id)).exists():
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 831, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 176, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'ir.actions.view'
```

animals.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class FarmAnimalsFarmAnimals(models.Model):
    _name ='farmanimal.farmanimal'

    name= fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    photo = fields.Binary(string='Image')
    sex = fields.Selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')], string='Sex')
    animal_dob = fields.Date(string='Date of birth/entry')
    animal_type = fields.Selection(
        [('cow','Cow'), ('bull','Bull'), ('goat','Goat'), ('sheep','Sheep'), 
        ('fish','Fish'), ('rabbit','Rabbit'), ('chicken','Chicken'), ('turkey','Turkey'),
        ('ducks','Ducks'),('quells','Quells'),('camel','Camel'), ('horse','Horse'),], 
        string='Animal Type')
```

feeds.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class FeedsFeeds(models.Model):
    _name ='feed.feed'

    f_name = fields.Char(string='Feed Name', required=True)
    f_photo  = fields.Binary(string='Product Image')
```

feed_records.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class FeedRecordsFeedRecords(models.Model):
    _name ='feedrecord.feedrecord'
    _inherits={'farmanimal.farmanimal','feed.feed'}

    feed_animal =  fields.Many2one( 'farmanimal.farmanimal','feed_animal_default_rel','name', string='Feed Animal',)
    feed_name = fields.Many2many('feed.feed', 'feed_default_rel', 'f_name', string='Consumed Feed(s)',)
    amount  = fields.Integer(string='Amount(In Grams)',)
    feed_date_time = fields.Datetime(string='Date and Time',default=fields.Datetime.now,)
```

vaccines.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class VaccinesVaccines(models.Model):
    _name ='vaccine.vaccine'

    v_name = fields.Char(string='Vaccine Name', required=True)
    v_photo  = fields.Binary(string='Product Image')
```

vaccinations_records.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class VaccinationRecordsVaccinationRecords(models.Model):
    _name ='vaccinationrecord.vaccinationrecord'
    _inherits={'farmanimal.farmanimal','vaccine.vaccine'}

    vaccinated_animal =  fields.Many2one( 'farmanimal.farmanimal','vaccinated_animal_default_rel','name', string='Vacinated Animal',)
    vaccine_name = fields.Many2many('vaccine.vaccine', 'vaccine_default_rel', 'v_name', string='Vaccine(s)',)
    vaccination_date_time = fields.Datetime(string='Date and Time',default=fields.Datetime.now,)
    next_vaccination_date = fields.Date(string='Next Date',)
```

diseases.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class DiseasesDiseases(models.Model):
    _name ='disease.disease'
    _inherits='vaccine.vaccine'

    d_name= fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    d_type = fields.Selection(
        [('infectious disease','Infectious Disease'), ('deficiency disease','Deficiency Disease'), ('hereditary disease','Hereditary Disease'), ('physiological diseases','Physiological Diseases')], string='Disease Type')
    s_vector = fields.Selection(
        [('airborne','Airborne'), ('foodborne','Foodborne'), ('infectious','Infectious'), ('lifestyle','Lifestyle'), ('non-communicable','Non-communicable')], 
        string='Spread Vector')
    threat_level = fields.Selection(
        [('high','High'), ('medium','Medium'), ('low','Low'), ('immediate quarantine','Immediate Quarantine')], string='Threat Level')
    cure = fields.Many2many('vaccine.vaccine', 'disease_cure_default_rel', 'v_name', string='Cure')
```

farm_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <odoo>
        <data>
            <record id="farm_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
                <field name="name">Animals</field>
                <field name="res_model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
                <field name="domain">[]</field>
                <field name="help" type="html">
                    <p class="or_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Animal

                    </p>
                </field>

            </record>
            <!--farm animals tree view-->
            <record id="farm_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">Animal Tree</field>
                <field name="model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <tree string="Animals">
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="sex"/>
                        <field name="animal_type"/>
                        <field name="animal_dob"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </record>
            <!--farm animals kanban view-->
            <record id="farm_kanban_view" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">farmanimal.farmanimal.kanban</field>
                <field name="model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <kanban class="o_res_farm_kanban">
                        <field name="id"/>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="sex"/>
                        <field name="animal_type"/>
                        <field name="animal_dob"/>
                        <templates>
                            <t t-name="kanban-box">
                                <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_global_click">
                                    <div class="o_kanban_image">
                                        <img alt="Avatar" t-att-src="kanban_image('farmanimal.farmanimal','photo',record.id.raw_value)"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="oe_kanban_details">
                                        <strong class="o_kanban_record_title">
                                            <field name="name"/>
                                        </strong>
                                        <div t-if="record.animal_type.value">
                                            <t t-esc="record.animal_type.value"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div t-if="record.sex.value">
                                            <t t-esc="record.sex.value"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div t-if="record.animal_dob.value">
                                            <t t-esc="record.animal_dob.value"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </t>
                        </templates>
                    </kanban>
                </field>

            </record>
            <!--farm animals form view-->
            <record id="farm_free_view" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">Animal Form</field>
                <field name="model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <form string="Animal">
                        <sheet>
                            <field name="photo" widget="image" class="oe_left oe_avatar" />
                            <div class="oe_title">
                                <h3>
                                    <field name="name"/>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <group>
                                <group>
                                    <field name="animal_type"/>
                                    <field name="sex"/>
                                </group>
                                <group>
                                    <field name="animal_dob"/>
                                </group>
                            </group>
                            <notebook>
                              <page string="Feeding Records">

                              </page>
                              <page string="Vaccination Records">

                              </page> 
                            </notebook>

                        </sheet>
                    </form>
                </field>
            </record>

            <menuitem id="farm_menu" name="Farm Management" action="farm_menu_action"/>
            <menuitem id="farm_animal_menu" parent="farm_menu"  name="Farm Animals"/>
        </data>
    </odoo>

farm_records_view.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="farm_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Animals</field>
            <field name="res_model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="or_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Animal

                </p>
            </field>

        </record>
        <!--farm animals tree view-->
        <record id="farm_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Animal Tree</field>
            <field name="model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Animals">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="sex"/>
                    <field name="animal_type"/>
                    <field name="animal_dob"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <!--farm animals kanban view-->
        <record id="farm_kanban_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">farmanimal.farmanimal.kanban</field>
            <field name="model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <kanban class="o_res_farm_kanban">
                    <field name="id"/>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="sex"/>
                    <field name="animal_type"/>
                    <field name="animal_dob"/>
                    <templates>
                        <t t-name="kanban-box">
                            <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_global_click">
                                <div class="o_kanban_image">
                                    <img alt="Avatar" t-att-src="kanban_image('farmanimal.farmanimal','photo',record.id.raw_value)"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="oe_kanban_details">
                                    <strong class="o_kanban_record_title">
                                        <field name="name"/>
                                    </strong>
                                    <div t-if="record.animal_type.value">
                                        <t t-esc="record.animal_type.value"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div t-if="record.sex.value">
                                        <t t-esc="record.sex.value"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div t-if="record.animal_dob.value">
                                        <t t-esc="record.animal_dob.value"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </t>
                    </templates>
                </kanban>
            </field>

        </record>
        <!--farm animals form view-->
        <record id="farm_free_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Animal Form</field>
            <field name="model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Animal">
                    <sheet>
                        <field name="photo" widget="image" class="oe_left oe_avatar" />
                        <div class="oe_title">
                            <h3>
                                <field name="name"/>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="animal_type"/>
                                <field name="sex"/>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="animal_dob"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                        <notebook>
                          <page string="Feeding Records">

                          </page>
                          <page string="Vaccination Records">

                          </page> 
                        </notebook>

                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="farm_menu" name="Farm Management" action="farm_menu_action"/>
        <menuitem id="farm_animal_menu" parent="farm_menu"  name="Farm Animals"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

feed_records_view.py

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="feeding_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Feeding Record</field>
            <field name="res_model">feedrecord.feedrecord</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="or_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Feeding Record

                </p>
            </field>           
        </record>
        <!--Feed tree view-->
        <record id="feed_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Feeding Record Tree</field>
            <field name="model">feedrecord.feedrecord</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Feeding Record">
                    <field name="feed_animal"/>
                    <field name="feed_name"/>
                    <field name="amount"/>
                    <field name="feed_date_time"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <!--feeding form view-->
        <record id="feeding_free_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Feeding Record Form</field>
            <field name="model">feedrecords.feedrecords</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Feeding Records">
                    <sheet>
                        <div class="oe_title">
                            <h1>
                                <field name="feed_animal"/>
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="feed_name"/>
                                <field name="amount"/>
                                <field name="feed_date_time"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>

                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

feeds_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="feeds_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Feeds</field>
            <field name="res_model">feed.feed</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kaban,tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="or_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Feed

                </p>
            </field>           
        </record>
        <!--Feed tree view-->
        <record id="feed_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Feeds</field>
            <field name="model">feed.feed</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Feeds">
                    <field name="f_name"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <!--feed kanban view-->
        <record id="feed_kanban_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">feed.feed.kanban</field>
            <field name="model">feed.feed</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <kanban class="o_res_farm_kanban">
                    <field name="id"/>
                    <field name="f_name"/>
                    <templates>
                        <t t-name="kanban-box">
                            <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_global_click">
                                <div class="o_kanban_image">
                                    <img alt="Avatar" t-att-src="kanban_image('feed.feed','f_photo',record.id.raw_value)"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="oe_kanban_details">
                                    <strong class="o_kanban_record_title">
                                        <field name="f_name"/>
                                    </strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </t>
                    </templates>
                </kanban>
            </field>
        </record>
        <!--feeding form view-->
        <record id="feed_free_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Feeds</field>
            <field name="model">feed.feed</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Feeds">
                    <sheet>
                        <field name="f_photo" widget="image" class="oe_left oe_avatar" />
                        <div class="oe_title">
                            <h1>
                                <field name="f_name"/>
                            </h1>
                        </div>                        
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to revisit how you are defining your `menuitem`s. Look at [the Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html#actions-and-menus) for reference.

The **Parent** menu(s) should not have any `action`. Only the final (child) menu should be assigned the action.

For example, instead of what you have currently:

```
<menuitem id="farm_menu" name="Farm Management"
    action="farm_menu_action"/>
<menuitem id="farm_animal_menu" name="Farm Animals"
    parent="farm_menu"/>
```

You ought to be doing this:

```
<menuitem id="farm_menu" name="Farm Management"/>
<menuitem id="farm_animal_menu" name="Farm Animals"
    parent="farm_menu"
    action="farm_menu_action"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was able to solve the problem but later run into another one, if you have sometime on your hands your help is highly welcome and appreciated. Please check out the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236792/how-do-i-fix-valueerror-dictionary-update-sequence-element-0-has-length-1-2-i?noredirect=1#comment106550178_60236792