# How do i fix ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required odoo 12?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to build a custom module and i have run into the following error, i added the models to `'depends':[]` and ended up with `KeyError: 'ir.actions.views'` when i remove the models from the `'depends':[]`, i get the error below:

```
2020-02-15 06:58:28,956 8372 ERROR mask_agro odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'mask_agro'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 188, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 240, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 470, in _build_model
    ModelClass._build_model_attributes(pool)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 535, in _build_model_attributes
    cls._inherits.update(base._inherits)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
2020-02-15 06:58:28,983 8372 INFO mask_agro werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2020 06:58:28] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 500 - 9 0.057 1.418
2020-02-15 06:58:29,007 8372 ERROR mask_agro werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'mask_agro'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mustaf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 304, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/mustaf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 292, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 434, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1320, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1293, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/home/mustaf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1471, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 117, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 62, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 188, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 240, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 470, in _build_model
    ModelClass._build_model_attributes(pool)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 535, in _build_model_attributes
    cls._inherits.update(base._inherits)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

manifest file

```
{
    'name': 'Farm Management',
    'version':'12.0.1.0.0',
    'summary':'Record and manage farm Information',
    'category':'Tools',
    'author':'Tumukunde Arnold',
    'maintainer': 'ADD Consultancy',
    'company':'ADD Consultancy',
    'website':'https://www.add.ug',
    'depends':['base'],
    'data':[
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/farm_view.xml',
        'views/diseases_view.xml',
        'views/feed_records_view.xml',
        'views/feeds_view.xml',
        'views/fvaccination_records_view.xml',
        'views/vaccines_view.xml',
    ],
    'images':[],
    'license':'AGPL-3',
    'installable':True,
    'application':False,
    'auto_install':False,
}
```

animals.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class FarmAnimalsFarmAnimals(models.Model):
    _name ='farmanimal.farmanimal'

    name= fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    photo = fields.Binary(string='Image')
    sex = fields.Selection([('male','Male'),('female','Female')], string='Sex')
    animal_dob = fields.Date(string='Date of birth/entry')
    animal_type = fields.Selection(
        [('cow','Cow'), ('bull','Bull'), ('goat','Goat'), ('sheep','Sheep'), 
        ('fish','Fish'), ('rabbit','Rabbit'), ('chicken','Chicken'), ('turkey','Turkey'),
        ('ducks','Ducks'),('quells','Quells'),('camel','Camel'), ('horse','Horse'),], 
        string='Animal Type')
```

diseases.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class DiseasesDiseases(models.Model):
    _name ='disease.disease'
    _inherits='vaccine.vaccine'

    d_name= fields.Char(string='Name', required=True)
    d_type = fields.Selection(
        [('infectious disease','Infectious Disease'), ('deficiency','Deficiency'), ('hereditary','Hereditary'), ('physiological','Physiological')], string='Disease Type')
    s_vector = fields.Selection(
        [('airborne','Airborne'), ('foodborne','Foodborne'), ('infectious','Infectious'), ('lifestyle','Lifestyle'), ('non-communicable','Non-communicable')], 
        string='Spread Vector')
    threat_level = fields.Selection(
        [('high','High'), ('medium','Medium'), ('low','Low'), ('quarantine','Quarantine')], string='Threat Level')
    cure = fields.Many2many('vaccine.vaccine', related='v_name', string='Cure')
```

feed_records.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class FeedRecordsFeedRecords(models.Model):
    _name ='feedrecord.feedrecord'
    _inherits={'farmanimal.farmanimal','feed.feed'}

    feed_animal =  fields.Many2one( 'farmanimal.farmanimal', related='name', string='Feed Animal',)
    feed_name = fields.Many2many('feed.feed', related='f_name', string='Consumed Feed(s)',)
    amount  = fields.Integer(string='Amount(In Grams)',)
    feed_date_time = fields.Datetime(string='Date and Time',default=fields.Datetime.now,)
```

feeds.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class FeedsFeeds(models.Model):
    _name ='feed.feed'

    f_name = fields.Char(string='Feed Name', required=True)
    f_photo  = fields.Binary(string='Product Image')
```

vaccination_records.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class VaccinationRecordsVaccinationRecords(models.Model):
    _name ='vaccinationrecord.vaccinationrecord'
    _inherits={'farmanimal.farmanimal','vaccine.vaccine'}

    vaccinated_animal =  fields.Many2one( 'farmanimal.farmanimal', related='name', string='Vacinated Animal',)
    vaccine_name = fields.Many2many('vaccine.vaccine', related='v_name', string='Vaccine(s)',)
    vaccination_date_time = fields.Datetime(string='Date and Time',default=fields.Datetime.now,)
    next_vaccination_date = fields.Date(string='Next Date',)
```

vaccines.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class VaccinesVaccines(models.Model):
    _name ='vaccine.vaccine'

    v_name = fields.Char(string='Vaccine Name', required=True)
    v_photo  = fields.Binary(string='Product Image')
```

diseases_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="disease_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Diseases</field>
            <field name="res_model">disease.disease</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="or_view_nocontent_create">Create The Disease Record

                </p>
            </field>           
        </record>
        <!--disease tree view-->
        <record id="disease_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Disease Tree</field>
            <field name="model">disease.disease</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Diseases">
                    <field name="d_name"/>
                    <field name="d_type"/>
                    <field name="s_vector"/>
                    <field name="threat_level"/>
                    <field name="cure"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <!--disease form view-->
        <record id="disease_free_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Disease Form</field>
            <field name="model">disease.disease</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Disease">
                    <sheet>
                        <div class="oe_title">
                            <h1>
                                <field name="d_name"/>
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="d_type"/>
                                <field name="s_vector"/>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="threat_level"/>
                                <field name="cure"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>

                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
        <menuitem id="disease_menu" name="Diseases" 
            parent="farm_view.farm_menu" action="disease_menu_action"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

farm_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="farm_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Animals</field>
            <field name="res_model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="or_view_nocontent_create">Create The First Animal

                </p>
            </field>

        </record>
        <!--farm animals tree view-->
        <record id="farm_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Animal Tree</field>
            <field name="model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Animals">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="sex"/>
                    <field name="animal_type"/>
                    <field name="animal_dob"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <!--farm animals kanban view-->
        <record id="farm_kanban_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">farmanimal.farmanimal.kanban</field>
            <field name="model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <kanban class="o_res_farm_kanban">
                    <field name="id"/>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="sex"/>
                    <field name="animal_type"/>
                    <field name="animal_dob"/>
                    <templates>
                        <t t-name="kanban-box">
                            <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_global_click">
                                <div class="o_kanban_image">
                                    <img alt="Avatar" t-att-src="kanban_image('farmanimal.farmanimal','photo',record.id.raw_value)"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="oe_kanban_details">
                                    <strong class="o_kanban_record_title">
                                        <field name="name"/>
                                    </strong>
                                    <div t-if="record.animal_type.value">
                                        <t t-esc="record.animal_type.value"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div t-if="record.sex.value">
                                        <t t-esc="record.sex.value"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div t-if="record.animal_dob.value">
                                        <t t-esc="record.animal_dob.value"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </t>
                    </templates>
                </kanban>
            </field>

        </record>
        <!--farm animals form view-->
        <record id="farm_free_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Animal Form</field>
            <field name="model">farmanimal.farmanimal</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Animal">
                    <sheet>
                        <field name="photo" widget="image" class="oe_left oe_avatar" />
                        <div class="oe_title">
                            <h3>
                                <field name="name"/>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="animal_type"/>
                                <field name="sex"/>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="animal_dob"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                        <notebook>
                          <page string="Feeding Records">

                          </page>
                          <page string="Vaccination Records">

                          </page> 
                        </notebook>

                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="main_farm_menu" name="Farm Management" />
        <menuitem id="farm_menu" name="Farm Management"
                  parent="main_farm_menu"/>
        <menuitem id="farm_animal_menu" name="Farm Animals" 
        parent="farm_menu" action="farm_menu_action"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I have tried a few solutions but none have worked. I think the issue is with my inheritance in the models and manifest dependencies but am at a dead end. Here is a link to the [module files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zh2v08FFELIxPXffAIdA1H65Co9xSFIJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In depends put the name of the app folder that contains the definition of the model, like sale.order is declared in sale module you should add sale to depends not the name of the model (the name of the app is the name of the folder)

Comment: @CharifDZ here is a link the module files https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zh2v08FFELIxPXffAIdA1H65Co9xSFIJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is `mask_agro`? I don't see it shown anywhere in the files you include in your question.

Comment: @travisw mask_agro is the database

Comment: @tumukundearnold I don't think I've ever seen a database name in a `KeyError` message. Can you create a new database, install your module, and see if you have the same problem?

Comment: @travisw That's why i am so confused. Let me give your solution a try.

Comment: Your problem is very simple, you are not using inherits the correct way or you are confused between _inherit and _inherits. I think you want to use inherit not inherits.

Comment: You need to read about the difference between these two

Comment: I finally deleted my database and recreated it and the module worked.